# I'm using Amazon S3 and want to create a form that sends out an email when submitted. How can i do this?

Tags: forms, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So the form i previously created didn't work because my site is hosted in Amazon S3. I just want a simple form that sends an email when the user clicks submit.

ron.capptivation.com/cappdev2

form is at the bottom

Any ideas on how to make this form work and send an email?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a back-end service to help you send the email.

You can use a Lambda function to send the email, then setup an API gateway to funnel your requests to the Lambda function.

Then in your static website, use Javascript to issue Ajax calls to the API gateway when the form is submitting.

Answer (score 1):

A static site on S3 can't process form submissions so you can't do this with just S3. You could either create your own server process to handle form submissions, possibly on EC2 or Lambda, or you could use a service like [Wufoo forms](http://www.wufoo.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The other respondents are correct in that you'll need a back-end service. One popular option is [formspree](https://formspree.io/). Another alternative would be posting a form's contents to something like Slack or HipChat using webhooks, such as explained in this [blog post](https://www.aerobatic.com/blog/post-a-jekyll-contact-form-to-slack).

Comment: Also check out [www.enformed.io](http://www.enformed.io), has a couple of interesting features, like setting the redirect after submiting, and email customization.